# Merge table cells for small screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I have something like this for big screens:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>title and image</th>
            <th>description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                title
                <br /><img scr="">
            </td>
            <td>
                few words about...
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I would like to change it to the following code for smaller screen:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>title and description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                title
                <br />few words about...
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Do you know how to do that properly? :)
I'd like to do it with CSS only but I can code in PHP and JS as well.

Thanks all and have a good day!

Comment: PHP is a server side only language. You could have it apply the appropriate style sheet but your question is really CSS/HTML related.

Comment: if you were just show/hiding elements depending on screen width you could easily get away with all css.. but looks like you are rearranging some of the html here.. you'd have to add additional elements that are hidden on larger widths, and visible on smaller widths. And vice versa with the smaller width elements to get away with all css here.. sorta gets messy that way though.. probably a better way.. fix up the html a bit and it could work out for ya

Comment: Going on what Rick says, consider this below. (working on it right now)

Answer (score 3):

You could - in a media query - use this CSS to convert the rows into cells and the cells into simple inline elements:

```css
tr {
  display: table-cell;
}

td {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>title and image</th>
      <th>description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        title
        <br /><img scr="">
      </td>
      <td>
        few words about...
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a css feature called a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) that allows you to apply css rules conditionally based on properties of the display. For instance, it could be used with a condition like `min-width(700px)` to target large screens and something like `max-width(320px)` for small screens.

The following approach will have repetition in your markup but if you're using PHP to render it, then you could reduce repeated code by storing the repeated markup in variables and referencing those.

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 321px) {
    .small-screen {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .large-screen {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="large-screen">
            <th>title and image</th>
            <th>description</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="small-screen">
            <th>title and description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="large-screen">
            <td>
                title
                <br /><img scr="">
            </td>
            <td>
                few words about...
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="small-screen">
            <td>
                title
                <br />few words about...
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

with css media queries, above a certain browser or screen width, show "wideDisplay" and hide "narrowDisplay". When the browser is small, hide "wideDisplay" and show "narrowDisplay".

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td class="wideDisplay">title and image</td>
<td class="wideDisplay">description</td >
<td class="narrowDisplay">title and description</td>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't. I tell myself the same thing all the time. There is a difference between knowing code and knowing what the best and more simple approach is to solve a problem. I often simplify code I wrote thinking why on earth I didn't think of this earlier.